# Error when connect my C script to a MySQL online Database

Tags: mysql, c

I'm trying to write a simple C script that can connect to an online MySQL Database. I have tried to use Connector/C (libmysqlclient) downloaded by https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/ but don't work.
Library  is recognized but when I'm compiling from terminal this is the result: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_mysql_init", referenced from: _main in test.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

I tried to correct the error described above, but I can not solve the problem with any help.
This is my code test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#define SIZE  30

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 /* connect to database */
 MYSQL mysql;   

  if(mysql_init(&mysql) == NULL){
    printf("Error\n");
    return 0;
 }

 /* other code */

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I'm compiling from terminal this is the result" which OS and compiler do you use and what command did you use..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379775/why-do-i-keep-getting-undefined-symbols-when-compiling-a-simple-mysql-c-applicat

Comment: I already tried to do it but this is the result
`clang: error: argument to '-l' is missing (expected 1 value)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland hi, i'm using macOS Mojave, my compiler is iTerm and I used this `gcc test.c`